# While installing node I get the prompt about my path

Tags: bash, node.js, path

**prompt**

```
Node was installed at

   /usr/local/bin/node

npm was installed at

   /usr/local/bin/npm

Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.
```

**How do I tell if it is in my path?**

bash profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/anderskitson/bin

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

#navigate to tech basics theme
alias techbasics='cd /Users/anderskitson/sites/techbasics/wp-content/themes/techBasicsCustom ; subl . '
```

**HEre is my echo**

```
Anderss-iMac:~ anderskitson$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/anderskitson/.rbenv/shims:/Users/anderskitson/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/anderskitson/bin
```

Comment: Typing echo $PATH should display everything in your path.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Roger added echo output

Comment: @AndersKitson: `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep '^/usr/local/bin$'` should make it easier for ***you*** to determine whether your path is correct or you need to update your Bash profile.

Comment: @Johnsyweb I get usr/local/bin so does that mean I am all good to go?

Comment: @AndersKitson: You should get `/usr/local/bin`, with the leading `/`. If you can run `npm`, then you're good to go!

Comment: @johnsyweb I get -bash command not found for npm?

Comment: And what do you get for `type /usr/local/bin/npm`?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I tell if it is in my path?

At the prompt:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep '^/usr/local/bin$'
```

If you see `/usr/local/bin`, then it is is in your $PATH.

If it's not there (and I'd be surprised were it not): you'll need to add the following to your Bash profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```

...and either `source` your Bash profile or start a new shell session.

Comment: I get the same output I edited about with the export... line.

Comment: OK. So... what do you conclude? I'll give you a clue: type `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $PATH` is a pretty easy way to tell for your own user, but will node be run by another user?  There may be an `/etc/init.d/node` that is run that will include it in the `$PATH`.  I wouldn't be worried about it, though.